# Praat script files are not running

Tags: audio, praat

I have installed praat and its working manually, but when I write any script and run it, it is showing errors. I have tried a simple command as follows:

> > writeInfoLine: "hello, world!"

and it's giving me following Error:

> > Unknown symbol:
> >     « writeInfoLine:
> >     Script line 3 not performed or completed:
> >     « writeInfoLine: "hello, world!" »
> >     Menu command "Run" not completed.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please make sure your installation is not broken. Here is my output: `hello, world!`. _Praat_ version: 6.0.19 on OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: This is not a problem with Praat but with your setup. What version of Praat are you using? What OS? How did you make the script? Does it run from the command line?

Comment: Thanks jja, I installed the latest version praat6.0.19 and it's working fine.